# How to smoothly transition between composables when switching states in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Row with two buttons, each setting a different state (SomeState.FirstState or SomeState.SecondState) when clicked. Depending on the state, I want to show a different composable, with smooth transitions between them.

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
) {
    Button(onClick = {
        state = SomeState.FirstState
    }) {
        Text(text = "Set first state")
    }
    Button(onClick = {
        state = SomeState.SecondState("Second state text")
    }) {
        Text(text = "Set second state")
    }
}

AnimatedVisibility(
    visible = state is SomeState.SecondState,
    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
) {
    if (state is SomeState.SecondState) {
        SecondStateText(state = state as SomeState.SecondState)
    }
}
```

The problem is that when SomeState.FirstState is set, the previous composable abruptly disappears. How can I smoothly transition between the composables when switching states, to provide a better user experience?

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't need to repeatedly check the **condition inside the AnimatedVisibility**. Content inside it will only show if the visible paramter is true.
2. Specify the enter & exit transition to provide a better animation when view gets visible/invisible.

   ```
    val enterTransition = fadeIn() + scaleIn() // Enter animation
    val exitTransition = fadeOut() + scaleOut() // Exit animation

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = state is SomeState.SecondState,
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
        enter = enterTransition,
        exit = exitTransition
    ) {
        SecondStateText(state = state as SomeState.SecondState)
    }

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = state is SomeState.FirstState,
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
        enter = enterTransition,
        exit = exitTransition
    ) {
        FirstStateText(state = state as SomeState.FirstState)
    }
   ```

Comment: I had almost the same code with a strict cast, and then the application crashed when state is changed

Comment: Can you please also share the error of the crash with this. It'll help to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use AnimatedContent to transition between your composable smoothly.
AnimatedContent is a container that automatically animates its content when targetState changes. Its content for different target states is defined in a mapping between a target state and a composable function.

```
@Composable
@Sampled
fun SimpleAnimatedContentSample() {
    // enum class ContentState { Foo, Bar, Baz }
    @Composable
    fun Foo() {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .size(200.dp)
                .background(Color(0xffffdb00))
        )
    }

    @Composable
    fun Bar() {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .size(40.dp)
                .background(Color(0xffff8100))
        )
    }

    @Composable
    fun Baz() {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .size(80.dp, 20.dp)
                .background(Color(0xffff4400))
        )
    }

    var contentState: ContentState by remember { mutableStateOf(ContentState.Foo) }
    AnimatedContent(contentState) {
        when (it) {
            // Specifies the mapping between a given ContentState and a composable function.
            ContentState.Foo -> Foo()
            ContentState.Bar -> Bar()
            ContentState.Baz -> Baz()
        }
    }
}
```

credit : https://www.composables.com/animation/animatedcontent